# using images in anim in animation-list

Tags: android, animation

[According to the docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource#View), this is how I would reference images for frame animation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/rocket_thrust1" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/rocket_thrust2" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/rocket_thrust3" android:duration="200" />
</animation-list>
```

But, since the `drawable` folder can't contain subfolders, putting 160 frames there would be a mess, I decided to put the images inside the `anim` folder,and when I try to do this:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@anim/rocket_thrust1" android:duration="200" />
    
</animation-list>
```

Android Studio doesn't really pick it up, i.e. it doesn't recognize the image is there. Is there anything I can do to point out the image is there? **Also**, can I put subdirectories inside the `anim` folder?

Comment: Why don't you create a single json file? it'll a lot better!

Comment: @Mr.Patel, json file?

Comment: Search for lottie animations!